# Interactive cmd.exe in Windows

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd

Is it possible to create an interactive cmd under Windows?

I am looking for a scripting solution to login to a server remotely which prompts password entering.

Take SSH as an example. A normal user will do the following at a command line window:

```
C:>ssh2 user@server.com "echo Hello"
user's password: ********
Hello
```

The second line, which prompts password entering, must be manually entered by a user. Stdin redirection does not work, for example,

```
ssh2 user@server.com "echo Hello" < password.txt  # not working
```

Therefore, I am looking for a script, which can impersonate a user. In Linux we can use expect, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user@server.com "ls"
expect *assword:
send "password\r"
```

I am looking for similar stuffs in Windows environment.

**Update:** If PowerShell can do the same, can someone paste a sample script? Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for PowerShell, not cmd.exe!

Comment: @John Saunders... i am believe in you ..so what is the code that he need?

Comment: @SiLentSoNG: I didn't have anything specific in mind. Only that PowerShell is so much more flexible than cmd.exe, and is designed to be hosted in another program, that cmd.exe should not even be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved.

Use a powershell that creates a Process object and play with that object.